# Is there a way to assign a tag's property as a variable in Sass/Css without Javascript?

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way to do something like this in Css/Scss (no Js):

```
#div1 { width: height + 20px; }
```

Or

```
#div2 { width: #div1.height + 50px;}
```

Or

```
$variable : #div1.height;
```

Comment: Anything possible with SCSS is actually possible with pure CSS. SCSS in the end compiles to ordinary CSS.

Comment: A big caveat to Wais's answer (it does answer the question) is that you cannot programmatically get the height of a div and then assign it to a variable and then add to that - since SASS/SCSS is compiled to CSS prior to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can almost achieve this using CSS variables together with `calc()`:

```
:root {
  --height: 40px;
}

#div1 {
  width: calc(var(--height) + 20px);
}

#div2 {
  width: calc(var(--height) + 70px);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, no you cannot do that, but I think it would be better to do it with javascript anyway because in css you wouldn't really need to do +50 you could just set it to 50.